# Sum of two sets

Tags: general-topology

Let $P$ and $Q$ be two non-empty subsets of a normed linear space $X$ and let $$P+Q=\{x+y\in X: x\in P\mbox{ and }y\in Q\}.$$ 
Then which of the following is FALSE?

1. If $P$ or $Q$ are convex, then $P+Q$ is convex.
2. If $P$ or $Q$ is open, then $P+Q$ is open.
3. P+Q must be closed if P and Q are closed.
4. If $P$ is closed and $Q$ is compact, then $P+Q$ is closed.

I think 1st is false, because if one set is not convex, then on addiction with a convex set, the resultant might not be convex.

But in one answer key, the answer is given as 3rd. In another, the answer is given as 4th. But I am not able to think of counter examples for either 3rd or 4th.

Comment: Clearly 4 can't be false unless 3 is also false, since compact sets are necessarily closed (in a metric space).  So any answer which says that only 4 is false must be incorrect.

Comment: 1 is very easily seen to be true: any convex combination $\lambda (p_1 + q_1) + (1-\lambda) (p_2 + q_2)$ can be written in the most obvious way as the sum of a point in $P$ and a point in $Q$.

Comment: @bof Ah thanks, I did not notice the "or" (probably because of the questionable use of "are" instead of "is").

Answer (score 2):

1 and 3 are false and the other two are true.
Counterexample for 1 is $P=[0,0.5]$ and $Q=[1,2]\cup[3,4]$, then $P+Q=[1,2.5]\cup[3,4.5]$, which is non-convex.
Counterexample for 3, as pointed out, is $P=\{-n+\frac{1}{n}:n\in N \}$
and $Q=N$, then $P+Q$ has subset $X=\{\frac{1}{n}:n\in N \}$ which has limit point at $0$ but $0 \notin P+Q$. 
Proof of 2 is as follows:
$$P+Q=\cup_{q\in Q} (P+q)$$
Now $P+q$ is open set is easy to see and the fact that union of open set is open gives us our result.
For 4 refer this [Proof check of sum of a compact and closed set of real numbers is closed](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/989313/proof-check-of-sum-of-a-compact-and-closed-set-of-real-numbers-is-closed)

Comment: But $N$ cannot be the usual $\mathbb{N}$ othewise your $P$ isn't properly defined. Did you mean $N=\mathbb{N}_{\geq 1}$ ? A cure could me to define $P$ as $\{-n+\frac{1}{n+1}\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ or $\{-n+\frac{1}{n}\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}_{\geq 1}}$. Thanks for the counter-example anayway !

Comment: I meant $N_{\ge 1}$.

Comment: What is the "spread" of the denotation $N=\mathbb{N}_{\geq 1}$ ? is it local ? (partly) US ? or other ?

Comment: @DuchampGérardH.E. The consensus on this site is that $\mathbb N$ is the positive integers, which I reluctantly conform to,

Comment: Perhaps a simpler example for 1. is $P=\{0\}$ and $Q=\{0,1\}.$..........+1

Comment: @user254665 I agree with this consensus, $\mathbb{N}=\{0,1,2,\cdots\}$ is very well spread (Bourbaki and  many others).