# If $C_1\subset \mathbb{R}^d$ is closed and $C_2\subset \mathbb{R}^d$ is compact then $C_1+C_2$ is closed

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Pardon me for the simple question but I can't figure it out.
Can someone give me the hint?
Well, I was thinking of using $C_1+C_2=\cup_{x\in C_1} (x+C_2)=\cup_{x\in C_2} (x+C_1)$ but this doesn't give me an answer.

Comment: Take  a sequence in $C_1+C_2$ converging to some point and show that the limit belongs to $C_1+C_2$.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll try

Comment: Bolzano–Weierstrass theorem may be useful.

Comment: What's wrong with the ff? $C_2$ is closed and bounded and thus is merely...idk just some translation/enlargening idk of $C_1$ soooo the sum is closed because $C_1 + C_2$ is closed

Comment: @BCLC Yes, you're right that $x+C_1$ is closed but it's an infinite union of closed sets so I couldn't conclude that the union is also closed.

Comment: Marking as an abstract duplicate of [Proof check of sum of a compact and closed set of real numbers is closed](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/989313/proof-check-of-sum-of-a-compact-and-closed-set-of-real-numbers-is-closed) note that the fact is more generally true in TV spaces but I've marked the duplicate with the idea that OP should be able to get what's going on there.

Comment: Thanks for the info jk001 i was imagining set addition all wrong. I thought adding 2 sets gives exactly 1 set from like 1 translation when it's actually potentially uncountable translations and thus its 1 set as a union of potentially uncountable translations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For closedness we can use the sequence criterion: $A \subseteq R^d$ is closed iff for every sequence $a_n \in A$ that converges to $a$ in $\Bbb R^d$, we have that $a \in A$ too.

So let $(x_n)$ converge to $x \in \Bbb R^d$, where all $x_n \in C_1 + C_2$. We want to show that $x \in C_1 + C_2$ as well.

We can write $x_n = a_n + b_n$ where $a_n \in C_1$ and $b_n \in C_2$.

We know that $(b_n)$, being a sequence in $C_2$, has a convergent subsequence so that we have $n_1 < n_2 < n_3 < \ldots$ and $b \in C_2$ so that $$b_{n_k} \to b \text{ as } k \to \infty $$

But then $$x_{n_k} = (a_{n_k} + b_{n_k}) \to x$$ as subsequences of convergent sequences have the same limit.

So $$a_{n_k} = x_{n_k} - b_{n_k} \to x - b$$ as the vector operations are continuous on $\Bbb R^d$ and now, as $C_1$ is closed, $$x-b \in C_1$$ so that $$x=(x-b) + b \in C_1 + C_2$$ as required and we've shown $C_1 + C_2$ is closed.

Do note that your formula works for infinite unions and so if either $C_1$ or $C_2$ are open, so is $C_1 + C_2$.

Comment: There is no doubt that this is a duplicate. That is the reason I posted a hint in a  comment and not an naswer.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I couldn't find one.